# Determine the bounds of a offline skmap mapcut

Tags: android, skmaps, skobbler-maps

Is there a way to retrieve the bounds of the mapcuts from the `*.skm` / `*.ngi` / `*.ngi.dat` files ?

We use several offline maps for a navigation feature and want to pre-check the possibility of some example routes in offline-mode.

Any solution is acceptable:

- Doing this within the (android) app with `java`
- Determine this with any other tool or language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the bounds of each mapcut from the Maps.json file. You can take it from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/72v2sxvldvasota/Maps.json?dl=0).
The coordinates are expressed like in this example:

```
"bbox": {
    "latMin": 41.1243,
    "latMax": 41.5271,
    "longMin": 19.5478,
    "longMax": 20.0842
  }
```

Comment: ty @Adrian.B! Is there a possibility to determine those values from skm files?

Comment: that is not possible - only the meta file (maps.json or maps.xml) can provide this information)

Comment: @Ando what about the ngi / ngi.dat files?

Comment: Those file contain the index files required for address & POI search for the skm bounding box

Comment: @Ando ok, yes. But could we determine (or calc) the bounding box from ngi / ngi.dat files?

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible.